# Where is the source code for the function refine(..) used in Matlab's estimateCameraParameters.m?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

At line 486 in `estimateCameraParameters.m` the `refine` function is called as shown below. Where is the source code of that function ?

I have searched all Matlab scripts but could not find it.

There is no documentation on this function either.

Any idea where to look for it ?

Where is `refine` hiding ?

```
errors = refine(stereoParams, imagePoints1(:, :, pairsUsed), ...
    imagePoints2(:, :, pairsUsed), shouldComputeErrors);
```

At line 303 there is a short description of this function :

```
% refine the initial estimate and compute distortion coefficients using
% non-linear least squares minimization
errors = refine(cameraParams, imagePoints, shouldComputeErrors);
```

Comment: Matlab is not open-source.  You can't expect to find the source code of every function.  Some of the functions, for example, are compiled code.

Comment: in this case you're a lucky: `edit refine` will give you the code. But be careful with editing and copyright!

Comment: hmmm... if I write edit refine I get refine.m does not exist... any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Found it: it's in `stereoParameters.m`

I just needed to start to step through `estimateCameraParameters.m` with the debugger.

**Additional explanation:**

http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/ordinary-methods.html

> Either of the following statements is correct syntax for calling a
>   method where obj is an object of the class defining the compute
>   method:

```
obj.compute(inc)
compute(obj,inc)
```

So refine() is a method **not** a standalone function.

I did not know that it is possible to call a method on an object using `method(object)` syntax. This was confusing me and I was thinking that `refine()` is a standalone method **not** defined within a class.